# Table join to KML file

Tags: kml, attribute-joins, excel

I want to add a classification to photos which are in an excel spreadsheet within a KML file.

Need a way to combine/join fields that are in an Excel spreadsheet to a KML file.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible with the [open-source program QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/). I recommend installing the **LTR (long-term release) version, QGIS 2.18**, because the documentation is much better than for the newest version.

1. Save the Excel file in CSV (comma-separated value) format.
2. Load the KML into a QGIS project.
3. (optional, but a good idea) Install the plugin QuickMapServices, and use it to add a basemap to your project. Compare the KML to the basemap and make sure it's in the correct location. If it's not, *do not proceed until you resolve the issue*. Otherwise your final export will be incorrectly geolocated.
4. Load the CSV file as an attribute-only table in the same QGIS
   project.
5. [Join](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=join#joins-properties) the table to the KML.
6. Export the joined layer in KML format.

See also:

- [QGIS User Guide](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/index.html)
- [QGIS Training Manual](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/index.html)
- [A Gentle Introduction to GIS](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/index.html)